# Merging according to Gitlab instructions does not work

Tags: git, merge, version-control, gitlab

Recently I bumped into something weird with Gitlab.

I created a Merge Request from the branch `release/v1.3.0` into the `master` branch that has been accepted.

Due to some conflicts in Gitlab, it cannot be directly merged via the Gitlab UI, fair enough, Gitlab proposed to merge locally:

> Step 1. Fetch and check out the branch for this merge request
>
> ```
> git fetch origin
> git checkout -b release/v1.3.0 origin/release/v1.3.0
> ```
>
> Step 2. Review the changes locally
>
> Step 3. Merge the branch and fix any conflicts that come up
>
> ```
> git fetch origin
> git checkout origin/master
> git merge --no-ff release/v1.3.0
> ```
>
> Step 4. Push the result of the merge to GitLab
>
> `git push origin master`

It seems that both branches (`master` and `release/v1.3.0`) are protected.

Anyway I then followed the instructions:

```
C:\Users\eperret\Desktop
λ git clone [my-gitlab-repository-address] ResolveConflicts
Cloning into 'ResolveConflicts'...
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/eperret/.ssh/id_ed25519':
remote: Enumerating objects: 3303, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (3303/3303), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1193/1193), done.
Rremote: Total 3303 (delta 2023), reused 3234 (delta 1966)eceiving objects:  98% (3237/3303)
Receiving objects: 100% (3303/3303), 1.60 MiB | 5.80 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2023/2023), done.

C:\Users\eperret\Desktop
λ cd ResolveConflicts\

C:\Users\eperret\Desktop\ResolveConflicts (develop -> origin)
λ git fetch origin
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/eperret/.ssh/id_ed25519':

C:\Users\eperret\Desktop\ResolveConflicts (develop -> origin)
λ git checkout -b release/v1.3.0 origin/release/v1.3.0
Switched to a new branch 'release/v1.3.0'
Branch 'release/v1.3.0' set up to track remote branch 'release/v1.3.0' from 'origin'.

C:\Users\eperret\Desktop\ResolveConflicts (release/v1.3.0 -> origin)
λ git fetch origin
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/eperret/.ssh/id_ed25519':
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/eperret/.ssh/id_ed25519':

C:\Users\eperret\Desktop\ResolveConflicts (release/v1.3.0 -> origin)
λ git checkout origin/master
Note: checking out 'origin/master'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at 8311614 Merge branch 'release/v1.2.0' into 'master'

C:\Users\eperret\Desktop\ResolveConflicts (HEAD detached at 8311614 -> origin)
λ git merge --no-ff release/v1.3.0
[Auto merge failing details]
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

# I resolved the conflicts in between

C:\Users\eperret\Desktop\ResolveConflicts (HEAD detached at 8311614 -> origin)
λ git commit -m "Resolve conflicts"
[detached HEAD 180a484] Resolve conflicts

C:\Users\eperret\Desktop\ResolveConflicts (HEAD detached at 180a484 -> origin)
λ git push origin master
error: src refspec master does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to [my-gitlab-repository-address]
```

So then I checked about the refs:

```
C:\Users\eperret\Desktop\ResolveConflicts (origin/master -> origin)
λ git show-ref
4996148e93ca64f3073047fb9a92ab16e03dbcd5 refs/heads/develop
4996148e93ca64f3073047fb9a92ab16e03dbcd5 refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
4996148e93ca64f3073047fb9a92ab16e03dbcd5 refs/remotes/origin/develop
8311614987d6df48d5d16d340c1b76a93b0600ba refs/remotes/origin/master
4996148e93ca64f3073047fb9a92ab16e03dbcd5 refs/remotes/origin/release/v1.3.0
8d2bd099e5de247ef38a3495d8601da9335272ff refs/tags/1.0.0
6e9deff7cdbc8cdcf56bf23dac02ff74a1ab2f22 refs/tags/1.0.1
447ca955fdbe83d5a3057ae43c120f2957a798f7 refs/tags/1.1.0
8cdd508715cb87104785a462090869041dcc2b72 refs/tags/1.1.1
8311614987d6df48d5d16d340c1b76a93b0600ba refs/tags/1.2.0
```

And tried to be a bit more specific:

```
C:\Users\eperret\Desktop\ResolveConflicts (HEAD detached at 180a484-> origin)
λ git push origin HEAD:master
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/eperret/.ssh/id_ed25519':
Enumerating objects: 1, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1/1), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1/1), 225 bytes | 225.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to push code to protected branches on this project.
To [my-gitlab-repository-address]
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to '[my-gitlab-repository-address]'
```

I am not sure to get it so... basically right from the start Gitlab instructions (knowing right from the beginning that the target branch is protected) tells you to do something that does not, sounds like it does not add up.

Anyway, any idea about how to merge my MR in that situation (knowing that the post conflicts commit is only local)?

---

[EDIT]

I found a few issues about the gitlab resolving conflicts feature:

- https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/59048
- https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/60101

In particular in the latter:

> If I don't have push permissions to the target branch, I won't be able to merge the change locally and push. It's confusing that the instructions are shown as if that is an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright the core of the issue was that the target (master) branch is protected so pushing things from a local repository cannot work.

Like I said in my edited post: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/60101

> If I don't have push permissions to the target branch, I won't be able to merge the change locally and push. It's confusing that the instructions are shown as if that is an option.

So basically the merge can only be performed from the UI since the push cannot be done locally (i.e. again the target branch is protected).

The merge request can be merged upon approval is there no conflicts that requires local conflicts resolution.

The solution was to create a new branch from `master` branch locally that is already merged (aka conflicts already resolved) with the `develop` branch before creating the actual branch (`release/vX.Y.Z`) to MR.

```
git clone [my-gitlab-repository-address] ResolveConflicts (if needed)
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git merge --no-ff develop
git commit -m "Resolve conflicts" (if needed)
git branch release/vX.Y.Z
git checkout release/vX.Y.Z
git push --set-upstream origin release/vX.Y.Z
```

Last and not the least, create the MR on Gitlab, from `release/vX.Y.Z` to `master`, getting it approved, merge from the UI.

Comment: @VahidJafari glad to know that my answer could help!

Answer (score 1):

Something went wrong when you ran `git checkout origin/master`. You ended up in a detached HEAD state rather than switching to the actual `master` branch.

I think you should be able to just use `git checkout master`. You may also need to `git pull origin master` after that to update your local master branch.

Hopefully by doing this you won't end up in a detached HEAD state. Then pushing back to master should work properly - `git push origin master`.

To summarize, for Step 3 in the GitLab instructions, instead try:

1. `git checkout master`
2. `git pull origin master`
3. `git merge --no-ff release/v1.3.0`

Then for Step 4:

1. `git push origin master`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, ultimately, I cannot push to master: `remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to push code to protected branches on this project.`
I think the workflow I have is fine when conflicts can be resolved via the Gitlab UI but everything locally cannot be applied. Hence the issue here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/60101

Comment: Yep. You may need to unprotect the branch, or add yourself as allowed to push. That issue is certainly relevant.

Comment: Well this is a production branch, it's not that clean to allow myself to push, I want to keep the peer approval system, hence my answer below, which fits my needs. I consider this issue more like a limitation of the Gitlab conflict resolution system.